# Causes of hot water flashes?

Tags: plumbing, water

I would like to learn more about possible causes of hot water flashes. More specifically when I shower, the water often (seemingly randomly) turns pretty hot for about 3 seconds and then goes back to the temperature that I originally set my water to.
The frequency of this appears to be pretty random.

I have a 60 gallon electric water heater.

Could anyone please share thoughts what could be causing this and whether it's something that could be fixed?

Comment: First thing that comes to mind is someone or something else is using cold water (turning on a tap, for example). Have you ruled that out completely, including anything outside, humidifiers, etc? If your shower valve is a pressure-balancing or a thermal-balancing valve (which would normally prevent this situation) it could be faulty in some way.. any chance you know the type of valve on your shower?

Comment: @gregmac - I don't know what type of valve I have. But I know of times when I experienced the hot water issue and nobody else was using (turning on/off) cold water in the house.  However, I sometimes notice a sound in the house that sound likes a little bit of water is being drained somewhere in the house (perhaps from the toilet tank). It sound like the toilet water tank gets rids of some extra water or something similar to it. I haven't really looked into the source of the sound but I suspect it may be related to the hot water issue. I will investigate and post the solution for this.